# Write a program in C to find the sum of digits of a number using recursion

Tags: c

I'm a newbie to c so this might be silly.Here I'm trying to find the sum of digits of a number using recursion. When I run the program I'm getting this error:

```
error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
```

MY CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void sum();
void main()
{

   char n[10];
   printf("enetr number");
   scanf("%s",n);
   int i=0;
   sum(i,n);
}

void sum(i,n)
{
   int a=strlen(n);
   static int s=0;
   if (i<a)
   {
      s=s+n[i]-'0';
      i++;
      return(sum(i++));
   }
   else if(i==a)
   {
     printf("%d",s);
   }
}
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Use proper prototypes and declarations/definitions! `void sum(int i, char *n);` and `int main(void);`

Comment: Yeah, declaring your function as `void sum(i, n)` is going to pass `n` as an `int`, not as an `int[]`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where you explicitely asked to handle the number as a string? Normally numbers (as long as they are not phone number, ccard numbers etc. or just way too large for any integer type)  are handled as integers.

Comment: The string is not a number. If they ask you to find sum of the digits of a number you need to read integral type and sum its digits.

Comment: Yes i'm aware that I'm not taking the input as a number like I'm supposed to do. I just wish to do the program by considering my number as a string and then proceed further.

Comment: @Bhavna do not convert to string as it is not needed. See my answer how to handle it

Answer (score 1):

You should arrange your recursion so that `sum()` calls itself with an ever-diminishing string. Ie, each `sum()` just returns the value of the first char in the given string *PLUS* the 'value' of the *remaining* string.  If `sum()`is passed an empty string, it *doesn't* call itself, and that is the end of the recursion.

Roughly this:

```
int sum(char *n)
{
    if (n[0] == '\0')
        return 0;
    else
        return n[0]-'0' + sum(n+1);
}
```

This way you don't even need to hold a static int with a "temporary sum on the side".

Comment: string is not number, You did the same mistake as OP.

Comment: @0___________ The question stated that "sum the digits of a number". It doesn't state that a number has to be represented as type `int`.

Comment: the number is not a string that's for sure. You can add numbers but you cant add string (in the numeric sense). Do you see the difference?

Comment: @0___________ why it can't be? The question never says that number has type `int`, or be represented as such. The OP clearly has the intent to represented number as string

Comment: If you do not understand the difference between the number and the string - then I'm really sorry.  Numbers can be added 5+4. Can you add strings "5" + "4"?

Comment: No, I do not say that you can add string. I say that number **can be**  represented as string.

Comment: Doesn not work for `sum("-123");`

Comment: @0___________Its true that numbers can't be represented as strings. But in this program the line ` s=s+n[i]-'0'; `  makes sure that the final value of s is an integer. So in the end we are getting the sum of digits right anyways.

Comment: @Bhavna no one can stop you from doing unnecessary and incorrect things. BTW does it count the digits of the `"-123"`. I don't think so. So this functions is not very good

Comment: @mmixLinus Thank you but do you know why I'm getting that above error?

Comment: @0___________oh yes you're right

Comment: @0___________ That's a problem, although an easy one to fix. Just check if `n[0]` is `-`

Comment: @justANewbie strings are not very friendly what about "      -123"?

Comment: @0___________ Still not that hard. Check all the conditions for `n[0]`. `'-'`, `' '`, `'+'` etc.

Comment: @Bhavna You haven't declared the types of your parameters to `sum()` so when you do `n[i]` you get a compilation error because the compiler thinks that `n` isn't an array. `sum(int i, char *n)`

Answer (score -1):

The string is not **number** as required in your task;

```
int sum(int number)
{
    int w = (number / 10) ? sum(number / 10) : 0;
    return abs(number % 10) + w;
}
```